# Как преобразовать string to int

Tags: java, строки, hex

Хочу задать цвет Textview в class1 через команду

```
textView.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt(class2.font1));
```

переменная font1 задана в class2 так:

```
public static String font1 ="0xff00ffff";
```

но программа вылетает, пробовал так

```
int ccc= Integer.valueOf(class2.font1);
textView.setTextColor(ccc);
```

тоже вылетает, может кто знает, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если содержимое font1 - это цвет в формате aarrggbb, то попробуйте так:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(class2.font1));
```

только при этом замените "0xff00ffff" на "#ff00ffff"

Comment: спасибо, этот вариант сработал

Comment: @user194394 можете пометить ответ как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 5):

`Integer.parseInt("ff0000", 16)` Где 16ть это разрядность числа. Для двоичной системы, например, надо использовать 2.

Если есть 0x, нужно воспользоваться  `Integer.decode("0x00ff0000");`

Answer (score 2):

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```